# How can i manage HTML code inside a variable?

Tags: python, html, string, authentication, web-scraping

Hello i have a problem with managing html code inside a variable.

I want to make a program that logs into account on website, then checks if something in the specific place has changed and if so then send me and email or some sort of notification.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

tab = []


payload = {
    'plates': 'login',
    'vin': 'password'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('url', data=payload)

    print (p.text)


soup = bs(p.text,'html.parser')

body = soup.find_all("li",{"class" : "state"},"span")


a = body[2]
print (a)
```

p.text is the whole html code

body looks like this

```
[<li class="state first">
<p><span>Przyjęto wniosek, trwa postępowanie administracyjne</span></p>
<img class="arrow" src="//cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status.png"/>
</li>, <li class="state active">
<p><span>Dokument został zamówiony</span></p>
<img class="arrow" src="//cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status_active.png"/>
</li>, <li class="state">
<p><span>Dokument do odbioru w urzędzie</span></p>
<img class="arrow" src="//cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status.png"/>
</li>, <li class="state last">
<p><span>Dokument wydany</span></p>
<img class="arrow" src="//cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status.png"/>
</li>]
```

body[2] looks like this:

```
<li class="state">
<p><span>Dokument do odbioru w urzędzie</span></p>
<img class="arrow" src="//cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status.png"/>
</li>
```

now my plan is to select only `src="//cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status.png"/>` from body[2]

then compare it to another variable containing the same text (the one in body[2] that i'm scraping from web will hopefully change some day)

if those 2 variables wont be identical then do something ( i think i will handle the message part)

I just dont know how to select the part i want.
Managing it like a string is hard because of all of those veird characters (<,>,",',/) etc.

I think i want my final solution to be something like this

```
if The_part_I_want == The old html code:
    pass
else:
    send me a notification
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the `img` element with `class=arrow` in `body[2]` and get its `src` attribute.

```
the_old_url = "//cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status.png"
img = body[2].find('img', class_='arrow')
if img and img['src'] == the_old_url:
    pass
else:
    send_notification()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I tried to print the "img" to see what is inside to check if this is the part i needed. As it turned out it is not. After printing it just says "None".

I just added to my code variable: 
the_old_url = 'src="//cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status.png"/>'

Maybe i just dont understand how to use your code?

Comment: `the_old_url` should just be `//cdn...`, it shouldn't have `src=` in it.

Comment: Is `None` the value of `img` or `img['src']`?

Comment: None is the value of img.
I also changed the_old_url to //cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status.png"/>
But it didnt work

Comment: If `img` is `None`, then there isn't actually an `<img class="state"...>` in `body[2]` as you show in the question. Check the value of `body[2]` again.

Comment: I double checked and its exactly the same as i posted in the question

Comment: Sorry, `_class=` should be `class_=`.

Comment: Thank you it works now. I had to change it a little bit because `img` and `img['src']` are not the same. I deleted the `img` from `if img and img['src'] == the_old_url` and i set 
`the_old_url` to be `//cdn.info-car.pl/webfiles/1590137977316/img/document/selected_status.png`
so if the `img['src']` will change i'll get a notification. Thank you one more time :)